# Update other values based on position and value of jQuery UI slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I'm building a basic mortgage calculator using jQuery and need to display some values which dynamically change based on the current value of the slider.

The values are basic maths such as displaying a percentage of the current slider value or displaying double the value of the current slider value.

Here's where I am with the jQuery and I imagine I need to somehow perform some maths on the last three lines to get the correct values and display these in the HTML elements.

HTML:

```
<div id="slider"></div>
<p>Your slider has a value of <span id="slider-value"></span></p>
<p>Double the slider value is <span id="slider-double"></span></p>
<p>10% of the slider value is <span id="slider-percent"></span></p>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#slider").slider({
value: 100,
min: 0,
max: 1000,
step: 1,
 slide: function(event, ui) {
$("#slider-value").html(ui.value);
}
});

$("#slider-value").html($('#slider').slider('value'));
$("#slider-double").html($('#slider').slider('value'));
$("#slider-percent").html($('#slider').slider('value'));
```

I'm working on it here where the html is also displayed: https://jsfiddle.net/chlorinekid/mwydgj82/6/

Any thoughts? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
    $("#slider").slider({
        value: 100,
        min: 0,
        max: 1000,
        step: 1,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $("#slider-value").html(ui.value);
            $("#slider-double").html(ui.value*2 + " double");
            $("#slider-percent").html(ui.value/10 + "%");
        }
    });

    $("#slider-value").html($('#slider').slider('value'));
    $("#slider-double").html($('#slider').slider('value')*2 + " double");
    $("#slider-percent").html($('#slider').slider('value')/10 + "%");
```

Comment: That seems to work, thanks. Is there a way to have the 'slider-double' and 'slider-percent' reflect the initial value of the slider (In this case '100') rather than only updating when the slider is moved? https://jsfiddle.net/chlorinekid/mwydgj82/22/

Comment: Please see my answer again.

Comment: Many thanks. One additional function that I need is to display a 'Remaining' value. This will show the result of value1 *minus* value2 *minus* value3. Any ideas on that? I assume that I somehow need to assign variables in order to subtract one from the other.

Comment: You can use something like this : `$("#slider-value").html(100 - ui.value);`

Answer (score 1):

> If you want to update slider affected values when slider value is chosen (when slider is released)

In order to retain previously set value in the slider one has to use `change` event of the slider.

```
$('#slider').slider({
    change: function(event, ui) {
      updateSliderDouble(ui.value);
      updateSliderPercent(ui.value);
    }
});
```

Please refer to my fiddle example
http://jsfiddle.net/mwydgj82/29/

> If you want to update slider affected values while slider is moving

in this case one has to use `slide` event of the slider.

```
$("#slider").slider({
    value: 100,
    min: 0,
    max: 1000,
    step: 1,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $("#slider-value").html(ui.value);
        updateSliderDouble(ui.value);
        updateSliderPercent(ui.value);
    }
});
```

Please refer to my fiddle example
http://jsfiddle.net/9ousgtyd/1/